# Bash daemon doesn't collect its chilidren

Tags: linux, unix, process, shell, bash

I've written this bash daemon that keeps an eye on a named pipe, logs everything it sees on a file named $LOG_FILE_BASENAME.$DATE, and it also creates a filtered version of it in $LOG_FILE_BASENAME.$DATE :

```
while true
do
    DATE=`date +%Y%m%d`
    cat $NAMED_PIPE | tee -a "$LOG_FILE_BASENAME.$DATE" | grep -P -v "$EXCEPTIONS" >> "$ACTIONABLE_LOG_FILE"
done
```

When the daemon is running, this is how the process table looks:

```
/bin/sh the_daemon.sh
 \_ cat the_fifo_queue
 \_ tee -a log_file.20150807
 \_ grep -P -v "regexp" > filtered_log_file
```

The problem is that when I kill the deamon (SIGTERM), the cat, the tee, and the grep processes that where spawned by the daemon are not collected by the parent. Instead, they become orphans and keep on waiting for input on the named pipe.

Once the FIFO receives some input, then they process that input as instructed and die.

How can make the daemon kill it's children before dying?

I know I could have the daemon manually collect the PIDs of its children and kill them before kicking the bucket, but isn't there an automated way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: recommended reading: **[Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773)**

Comment: We don't accept implementation questions here, sorry.  Please wait while we migrate your question to Stack Overflow.